# error C2079: 'myMath' uses undefined class 'mathTools

Tags: c++

I have a file called Utils.h. I put some classes in it. the name of these classes are: `Point`, `Edge`,`Cone` and `mathTools`.I have two other files called `RedBlackTree.h` and `RedBlackTree.cpp` they hold the declaration and implementation of class `RedBlackTree`. My main() function is in `source.cpp`. I can include both `Utils.h` and `RedBlackTree.h` in it and there is no problem. but when I include `Utils.h` in 'RedBlackTree.h' I face error C2079. I heard that its because circular dependency in headers, but I cant it here.
One other strange error is: `error C2370: 'max_input_size' : redefinition; different storage class` and again if I do not include `"Utils.h"` in `RedBlackTree.h` this error wont happen.

**Edit:**
if I write `mathTools *myMath;` instead of `mathTools myMath;` and do so for other classes I wont have this problem.

My Utils.h looks like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323
#define and &&
#define or ||

#define TETA 30.0f
#define OMEGA 0.15f

const int max_input_size = 50;
//const unsigned long long INF = 2147483647;
#define INF 2147483647


class Point{
public:
/*
Some Functions
*/

private:
/*
. . . 
*/
};

class Edge{
public:
// . . . 
private:
// . . . 
};

class Cone{
public:
// . . .
};

class mathTools{
public:// . . . 
private:// . . .
};
```

RedBlackTree.h

```
#include "Utils.h" //if I comment this line, there wont be error C2097 

#pragma once

// class prototype
template <class Comparable>
class RedBlackTree;

template <class Comparable>
class RBTreeNode{
    /*
    .
    .
    .
    */
friend class RedBlackTree<Comparable>;
};

template <class Comparable>
class RedBlackTree
{
public:
    //...

private:
    //...
};
```

source.cpp

```
#include "Utils.h"
#include "RedBlackTree.cpp"


//____________________GLOBAL VARIABLES
mathTools myMath; //error C2079: 'myMath' uses undefined class  'mathTools'
              // and there are lots of errors after it

std::vector<Cone>cones;
std::vector<Point>input;
std::vector<Edge> outLawEdges;

bool E[max_input_size][max_input_size] = { false };
double t_sp[max_input_size][max_input_size] = { (double)INF };
double FW[max_input_size][max_input_size] = { (double)INF };
double dist[max_input_size][max_input_size] = { (double)INF };

int main(){
// . . . 
}
```

Comment: `#include "RedBlackTree.cpp"` ? cpp ??

Comment: Move `#pragma once` before all other includes.

Comment: Did you try to compile the code as pasted here, to see if it still fails?  If it doesn't try to add lines from the original until it fails and see what the source of the problem is.

Comment: You can already use `and` and `or` in place of `&&` and `||`. Do not redefine them.

Comment: @chris Im using MSVS 2013 and if I do not define `and` and `or` it gives me: `error C2065: 'and' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: Compile with `/Za` to disable the extensions and they should work. They're most certainly standard.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am using [this](http://larryvdh.com/blog/red-black-tree-implementation/) RedBlackTree. in `main.cpp` he included "RedBlackTree.cpp" is that wrong?

Comment: @MoNo Including .cpp files in main works in small examples but not in general, so we wouldn't expect it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C and C++ programming languages, an #include guard, sometimes called a macro guard, is a particular construct used to avoid the problem of double inclusion when dealing with the include directive. The addition of #include guards to a header file is one way to make that file idempotent.([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)). change your `Utils.h` and `RedBlackTree.h` like this:

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H
//Utils.h codes 
#endif
```

and

```
#ifndef RED_BLACK_TREE_H
#define RED_BLACK_TREE_H
//RedBlackTree.h codes
#endif
```